# Python: How to remove external punctuation using regex and ignore the internal punctuation?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Example:

> input: @#$abef*&
>
> output: abef

Comment: input: @#$ab<ghi>ef*& output: ab<ghi>ef

Answer (score 0):

I know you've asked about solving using regular expressions, but here is an alternative over-complicated solution using [`itertools.dropwhile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) and [`str.isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha):

```
In [1]: from itertools import dropwhile

In [2]: s = "@#$ab<ghi>ef*&"

In [3]: is_not_alpha = lambda x: not x.isalpha()

In [4]: ''.join(list(dropwhile(is_not_alpha, list(dropwhile(is_not_alpha, s))[::-1]))[::-1])
Out[4]: 'ab<ghi>ef'
```

Here, we are, basically, applying the "is not alpha" condition from both sides of the string.